# Clear all text on current line from a bash script

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

How can I cause <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> from a bash script?

Ie I want to remove all characters left of cursor on a line, and put cursor in column 0.

A workaround could be printing `\r`, followed by something to clear right of cursor.

I don't want to clear the whole terminal screen.

**Update:**

The solution I use (in PHP):

```
echo 'mydata' . "\033[0K\r";
```

Comment: I found a working answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5861713/129202 so I guess I could delete my question as duplicate :-P

Answer (score 5):

Basically you can do something like this:

```
while :; do # an infinite loop just for demonstration
    echo "$RANDOM" # print your stuff here
    sleep 0.2
    tput cuu1 # move cursor up by one line
    tput el # clear the line
done
```

Use `man tput` for more info. To see the list of capabilities use `man terminfo`