# Have script sleep between echo commands

Tags: bash, shell, time, echo, sleep

I'm sure someone has already asked this before or maybe it is impossible through a bash script, but I have not found anything so I'm going to ask!

I want a script to echo something like:

```
please wait...
```

But I want the dots to have time between them so it will start by saying, "please wait" and after a second or so add a dot.

Any help is appreciated!
George

Comment: `echo -n please wait; while true; do sleep 1; echo -n .; done`.

Comment: Please post answers as answers, not comments.

Comment: You might like ``tput``. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24319981/2698019

Comment: @Cyrus write your comment as an answer and I will mark it correct. Worked like a charm! Thanks man